# Pandas - lambda - values in list and corresponding value from another column where values in list

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Consider the below dataframe:

```
   Name    identifierOne              identifierTwo
0  Name1   ['12032', '444', '555']    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
1  Name2   ['666', '51206', '777']    ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
2  Name3   ['111', '222', '333']      ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']
```

I can get the row of the entry where 'identifierOne' has a '120' with:

```
print(df[df['identifierOne'].apply(lambda x: '120' in str(x))][['Name', 'identifierOne', 'identifierTwo']])
```

which will return:

```
   Name    identifierOne              identifierTwo
0  Name1   ['12032', '444', '555']    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
1  Name2   ['666', '51206', '777']    ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
```

How can I get a) just the item in the list that has '120' and b) it's corresponding value from 'identifierTwo'? Expected Output:

```
   Name    identifierOne    identifierTwo
0  Name1   ['12032']        ['aaa']
1  Name2   ['51206']        ['eee']
```

or just the string:

```
   Name    identifierOne    identifierTwo
0  Name1   '12032'          'aaa'
1  Name2   '51206'          'eee'
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the values as a list or as a string? looks like you have a string representation of a list. And what is your pandas version?

Comment: Any of the two would suffice, I tried to explain that at the end of the question with how an acceptable output would look like i.e either the string item in the list or just the string outside of a list object. Pandas version: 1.2.2

Comment: `str(x)` is not a good way to turn a list into string. It might get stripped off

Comment: What would be a better way within the python-lambda-pandas context of the above example?

Comment: `df.apply(pd.Series.explode).query('identifierOne.str.contains("120")', engine='python')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting to list then using `explode`, `concat` and `df.query` we can do below:

---

First convert your string representation of a list to an actual list (*ignore this step if the input is already a list*)

```
import ast
df[['identifierOne', 'identifierTwo']] = (df[['identifierOne', 'identifierTwo']]
                                         .applymap(ast.literal_eval))
```

---

Explode the columns and concat them and finally using `df.query` , filter the necessary rows and then join the 'Name' column.

```
cols = ['identifierOne','identifierTwo']
out = (pd.concat([df[col].explode() for col in cols],axis=1,keys=cols)
      .query("identifierOne.str.contains('120')",engine='python').join(df[['Name']]))
```

Or Method 2 -  Using a callable:

```
cols = ['identifierOne','identifierTwo']
out = (pd.concat([df[col].explode() for col in cols],axis=1,keys=cols)
       .join(df[['Name']]).loc[lambda x: x['identifierOne'].str.contains('120')])
```

---

```
print(out)

  identifierOne identifierTwo   Name
0         12032           aaa  Name1
1         51206           eee  Name2
```

Comment: I found this approach the most flexible for a large dataset as I can first .loc dataframe for the rows with the matches, then call your method 2 on those rows and then .apply(literal_eval) on a those rows rather than the whole dataframe.
In my case I am using your method 2 on the smaller dataframe like so: 
out = (pd.concat([df[col].apply(literal_eval).explode().dropna() for col in cols], axis=1, keys=cols).join(df[['name']]).loc[lambda x: x['V'].str.contains('120')]) that returns the values instantly while calling .apply(literal_eval) first on the whole dataset takes minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `apply` function which can be used to iterate over your data and write to a new DataFrame called `output`.

```
# construct an output df
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
output['Name'] = df['Name']

def findvalue(df, value):
    # check the words which contain the value
    inlist = [value in word for word in df['identifierOne']]
    try:
        # this will throw error if True is not found
        index = inlist.index(True)

        # but if there is a True, write the correct things to `output`
        one = df['identifierOne'][index]
        two = df['identifierTwo'][index]
        output.loc[df.name, 'identifierOne'] = one
        output.loc[df.name, 'identifierTwo'] = two

    except ValueError:
        return
```

With this, you can `apply` the function like so:

```
lookfor = '120'
df.apply(findvalue, axis=1, value=lookfor)
```

Result (i.e., `output`):

```
    Name identifierOne identifierTwo
0  Name1         12032           aaa
1  Name2         51206           eee
2  Name3           NaN           NaN

# note that these are strings, all dypes == object
```

This is very loop heavy, so I imagine is not the fastest answer.  But I think the logic is a little more basic.

One quick note is that the `inlist.index(True)` operation is only returning the index of the *first* `True` in the list.  If you anticipate having multiple occurrences of the value within each cell, then you could do the following `findvalue`:

```
def findvalue(df, value):
    # check the words which contain the value
    inlist = [value in word for word in df['identifierOne']]

    one = []
    two = []

    # now we explicitly check all of the booleans in `inlist`
    for i, boolean in enumerate(inlist):
        if boolean:
            one.append(df['identifierOne'][i])
            two.append(df['identifierTwo'][i])

    # only write to `output` if there is something to write
    if one:
        output.loc[df.name, 'identifierOne'] = one
        output.loc[df.name, 'identifierTwo'] = two
```

For the same example, the result is now in lists (of strings):

```
    Name identifierOne identifierTwo
0  Name1       [12032]         [aaa]
1  Name2       [51206]         [eee]
2  Name3           NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
>>> df

    Name      identifierOne    identifierTwo
0  Name1  [12032, 444, 555]  [aaa, bbb, ccc]
1  Name2  [666, 51206, 777]  [ddd, eee, fff]
2  Name3    [111, 222, 333]  [ggg, hhh, iii]

>>> s1 = df['identifierOne'].explode()
>>> s2 = df['identifierTwo'].explode()
>>> cond = s1.str.contains('120')

>>> df.assign(identifierOne=s1[cond], identifierTwo=s2[cond]).dropna()
    Name identifierOne identifierTwo
0  Name1         12032           aaa
1  Name2         51206           eee
```

**NOTE:**

If initially `identifier` columns are `str` representation of `list`, then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval

>>> df[['identifierOne', 'identifierTwo']] = (
        df.filter(like='identifier').applymap(literal_eval)
    )
```

Comment: I have been trying to make your solution work and apart for some issues in my dataframe that I just discovered, is there a possibility that identifierTwo=s2[cond] was meant to be just identifierTwo=s2?

Comment: On my end when I run it with identifierOne=s1[cond], identifierTwo=s2[cond] it returns the same value (the one under identifierOne) for both columns while when I remove [cond] from  identifierTwo=s2[cond], i.e identifierOne=s1[cond], identifierTwo=s2 it returns the expected value

Comment: Can't understand why that would happen :P

Comment: I will run further tests and double confirm in case something else is wrong in my dataframe but out of curiosity, is there a way that I can go through the items in the list based on the index value of the match? i.e if the matched value is in identifierOne[0], grab identrifierTwo[0]?

Exploding these particular columns in my dataframe expands it from 30k rows to 300k and takes time, unless my suggestion above would be even slower.

Comment: I am not sure. Let me check.

Comment: Tested another solution, without explode, but it is 2.25 x slower than the current solution. Can't think of any better method.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will finish my testing and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my entire thought process:

```
In [314]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name='Name1 Name2 Name3'.split(), id1=[['12032', '444', '555'], ['666', '51206', '777'], ['111', '222', '333']], id2=[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff'], ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']]))                                                 

In [315]: df['id1e'] = df.id1.apply(lambda L:list(enumerate(L)))                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [316]: df['id2e'] = df.id2.apply(lambda L:list(enumerate(L)))                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [317]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[317]: 
    Name                id1              id2                              id1e                            id2e
0  Name1  [12032, 444, 555]  [aaa, bbb, ccc]  [(0, 12032), (1, 444), (2, 555)]  [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc)]
1  Name2  [666, 51206, 777]  [ddd, eee, fff]  [(0, 666), (1, 51206), (2, 777)]  [(0, ddd), (1, eee), (2, fff)]
2  Name3    [111, 222, 333]  [ggg, hhh, iii]    [(0, 111), (1, 222), (2, 333)]  [(0, ggg), (1, hhh), (2, iii)]

In [318]: df.drop('id1 id2'.split(), axis=1, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [319]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[319]: 
    Name                              id1e                            id2e
0  Name1  [(0, 12032), (1, 444), (2, 555)]  [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc)]
1  Name2  [(0, 666), (1, 51206), (2, 777)]  [(0, ddd), (1, eee), (2, fff)]
2  Name3    [(0, 111), (1, 222), (2, 333)]  [(0, ggg), (1, hhh), (2, iii)]

In [320]: df.explode('id1e')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[320]: 
    Name        id1e                            id2e
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc)]
0  Name1    (1, 444)  [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc)]
0  Name1    (2, 555)  [(0, aaa), (1, bbb), (2, ccc)]
1  Name2    (0, 666)  [(0, ddd), (1, eee), (2, fff)]
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  [(0, ddd), (1, eee), (2, fff)]
1  Name2    (2, 777)  [(0, ddd), (1, eee), (2, fff)]
2  Name3    (0, 111)  [(0, ggg), (1, hhh), (2, iii)]
2  Name3    (1, 222)  [(0, ggg), (1, hhh), (2, iii)]
2  Name3    (2, 333)  [(0, ggg), (1, hhh), (2, iii)]

In [321]: df = df.explode('id1e')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [322]: df = df.explode('id2e')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [323]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[323]: 
    Name        id1e      id2e
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (0, aaa)
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (1, bbb)
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (2, ccc)
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (0, aaa)
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (1, bbb)
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (2, ccc)
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (0, aaa)
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (1, bbb)
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (2, ccc)
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (0, ddd)
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (1, eee)
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (2, fff)
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (0, ddd)
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (1, eee)
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (2, fff)
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (0, ddd)
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (1, eee)
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (2, fff)
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (0, ggg)
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (1, hhh)
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (2, iii)
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (0, ggg)
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (1, hhh)
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (2, iii)
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (0, ggg)
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (1, hhh)
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (2, iii)

In [324]: df['id1i'] = df.id1e.apply(lambda t:t[0])                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [325]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[325]: 
    Name        id1e      id2e  id1i
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (0, aaa)     0
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (1, bbb)     0
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (2, ccc)     0
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (0, aaa)     1
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (1, bbb)     1
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (2, ccc)     1
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (0, aaa)     2
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (1, bbb)     2
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (2, ccc)     2
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (0, ddd)     0
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (1, eee)     0
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (2, fff)     0
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (0, ddd)     1
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (1, eee)     1
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (2, fff)     1
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (0, ddd)     2
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (1, eee)     2
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (2, fff)     2
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (0, ggg)     0
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (1, hhh)     0
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (2, iii)     0
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (0, ggg)     1
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (1, hhh)     1
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (2, iii)     1
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (0, ggg)     2
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (1, hhh)     2
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (2, iii)     2

In [326]: df['id2i'] = df.id2e.apply(lambda t:t[0])                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [327]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[327]: 
    Name        id1e      id2e  id1i  id2i
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (0, aaa)     0     0
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (1, bbb)     0     1
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (2, ccc)     0     2
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (0, aaa)     1     0
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (1, bbb)     1     1
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (2, ccc)     1     2
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (0, aaa)     2     0
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (1, bbb)     2     1
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (2, ccc)     2     2
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (0, ddd)     0     0
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (1, eee)     0     1
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (2, fff)     0     2
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (0, ddd)     1     0
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (1, eee)     1     1
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (2, fff)     1     2
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (0, ddd)     2     0
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (1, eee)     2     1
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (2, fff)     2     2
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (0, ggg)     0     0
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (1, hhh)     0     1
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (2, iii)     0     2
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (0, ggg)     1     0
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (1, hhh)     1     1
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (2, iii)     1     2
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (0, ggg)     2     0
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (1, hhh)     2     1
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (2, iii)     2     2

In [328]: df['id1'] = df.id1e.apply(lambda t: t[1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [329]: df['id2'] = df.id2e.apply(lambda t: t[1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [330]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[330]: 
    Name        id1e      id2e  id1i  id2i    id1  id2
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (0, aaa)     0     0  12032  aaa
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (1, bbb)     0     1  12032  bbb
0  Name1  (0, 12032)  (2, ccc)     0     2  12032  ccc
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (0, aaa)     1     0    444  aaa
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (1, bbb)     1     1    444  bbb
0  Name1    (1, 444)  (2, ccc)     1     2    444  ccc
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (0, aaa)     2     0    555  aaa
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (1, bbb)     2     1    555  bbb
0  Name1    (2, 555)  (2, ccc)     2     2    555  ccc
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (0, ddd)     0     0    666  ddd
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (1, eee)     0     1    666  eee
1  Name2    (0, 666)  (2, fff)     0     2    666  fff
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (0, ddd)     1     0  51206  ddd
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (1, eee)     1     1  51206  eee
1  Name2  (1, 51206)  (2, fff)     1     2  51206  fff
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (0, ddd)     2     0    777  ddd
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (1, eee)     2     1    777  eee
1  Name2    (2, 777)  (2, fff)     2     2    777  fff
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (0, ggg)     0     0    111  ggg
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (1, hhh)     0     1    111  hhh
2  Name3    (0, 111)  (2, iii)     0     2    111  iii
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (0, ggg)     1     0    222  ggg
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (1, hhh)     1     1    222  hhh
2  Name3    (1, 222)  (2, iii)     1     2    222  iii
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (0, ggg)     2     0    333  ggg
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (1, hhh)     2     1    333  hhh
2  Name3    (2, 333)  (2, iii)     2     2    333  iii

In [331]: df.drop('id1e id2e'.split(), axis=1, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [332]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[332]: 
    Name  id1i  id2i    id1  id2
0  Name1     0     0  12032  aaa
0  Name1     0     1  12032  bbb
0  Name1     0     2  12032  ccc
0  Name1     1     0    444  aaa
0  Name1     1     1    444  bbb
0  Name1     1     2    444  ccc
0  Name1     2     0    555  aaa
0  Name1     2     1    555  bbb
0  Name1     2     2    555  ccc
1  Name2     0     0    666  ddd
1  Name2     0     1    666  eee
1  Name2     0     2    666  fff
1  Name2     1     0  51206  ddd
1  Name2     1     1  51206  eee
1  Name2     1     2  51206  fff
1  Name2     2     0    777  ddd
1  Name2     2     1    777  eee
1  Name2     2     2    777  fff
2  Name3     0     0    111  ggg
2  Name3     0     1    111  hhh
2  Name3     0     2    111  iii
2  Name3     1     0    222  ggg
2  Name3     1     1    222  hhh
2  Name3     1     2    222  iii
2  Name3     2     0    333  ggg
2  Name3     2     1    333  hhh
2  Name3     2     2    333  iii

In [333]: df[df.id1.apply(lambda x: '120' in str(x))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[333]: 
    Name  id1i  id2i    id1  id2
0  Name1     0     0  12032  aaa
0  Name1     0     1  12032  bbb
0  Name1     0     2  12032  ccc
1  Name2     1     0  51206  ddd
1  Name2     1     1  51206  eee
1  Name2     1     2  51206  fff

In [334]: df = df[df.id1.apply(lambda x: '120' in str(x))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [335]: df[df.id1i == df.id2i]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[335]: 
    Name  id1i  id2i    id1  id2
0  Name1     0     0  12032  aaa
1  Name2     1     1  51206  eee

In [336]: df[df.id1i == df.id2i]['id1 id2'.split()]                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[336]: 
     id1  id2
0  12032  aaa
1  51206  eee
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with apply and without imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([['Name1' , ['12032', '444', '555'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']],
                ['Name2', ['666', '51206', '777'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']],
                ['Name3', ['111', '222', '333'], ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']]],columns=['Name','identifierOne','identifierTwo'])

# this loops the items inside the series in the apply function
idx = df['identifierOne'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(x.index(y)) if '120' in str(y) else '' for y in x]))

rowindex = df[idx != ''].index
listindex = idx.iloc[rowindex].astype(int)
listindex.name = 'listindex'
subset = df[df.index.isin(rowindex)]
subset.index = subset.index.astype(int)
concat = pd.merge(subset, listindex, left_index=True, right_index=True)
concat['identifierOne'] = concat.apply(lambda x: x['identifierOne'][x['listindex']], axis=1)
concat['identifierTwo'] = concat.apply(lambda x: x['identifierTwo'][x['listindex']], axis=1)
```

Giving the result:

```
concat[['Name','identifierOne','identifierTwo']]

Name    identifierOne   identifierTwo
0   Name1   12032   aaa
1   Name2   51206   eee
```